# Tomcat pooling connection to replication database

Tags: java, sql-server, database, tomcat, jdbc

I have a tomcat with connections registered in my context.xml. This connects to a database that is a replication of a production database. This database is restored every 3 hours and then my connection manager in tomcat looses this connection. This means every 3 hours I would have to restart my application to retrieve a new database connection.
This is the exception I am getting

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
```

I there a way I can configure an other connection type in my tomcat so that it does not loose my connection each restore of the database?

db connection config in context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/db"
              auth=""
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100"
              maxIdle="30"
              maxWait="10000"
              username=""
              password=""
              driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;DatabaseName=db"/>
```

jndi config in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/db</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

jpa connection manager in spring config

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource"
                     jndi-name="jdbc/db"
                     expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

   <bean id="emf"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="firaPU"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: You should obtain a connection when you need it and close it as soon as you are done with it. You don't show any code, but "I would have to restart my application to retrieve a new database connection" suggests that you allocate a connection at start up and hold on to it. Most likely the connection pool manager has reclaimed it as a 'leaking' connection. However note that technically a call to [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) should never throw an `SQLException` if the connection is already closed.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel surely the idea behind DBCP is to hold open connections.  See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: @ScaryWombat Of course it is, but a user of the connection pool should acquire and release the logical connection ASAP. When the user closes the connection, it is returned to the pool (not physically closed). That makes sure that the pool doesn't have to acquire too many connections. It should also allow the pool to more easily recover from disconnects (as long as validity checks are supported by and enabled in the connection pool). Most pools also reclaim logical connections that are held too long (as it usually indicates a connection leak).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You second comment explains it well.

Comment: I've added my spring config and other configuration. If I follow your explanation @MarkRotteveel, my jpa config isn't configured correctly because it does not release its connection. After every db transaction I do see this log message
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils : Closing JPA EntityManager

Comment: The default DBCP config does a validity test on borrow, so unless `Connection.isValid` isn't implemented in SQL Server JDBC (or you are using an old driver or DBCP) I'd expect DBCP to automatically recover from replacing the database.

Comment: So this isn't the case, where do I go looking to solve this issue?